# Flask: differences between request.form["xxxxx"], request.form.get("xxxxxx") and request.args.get("xxxxx")?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

What are the differences between `flask.request.form["xxx"]` , `flask.request.form.get("xxx")` and `flask.request.args.get("xxx")` ?

I have this question because I am using flask-login to handle authentication.
In particular in the following code (taken from the flask-login github page), I don't understand why with `req.form.get("email")`, email is `None`, while with `req.form["email"]`, email hasn't a value. Here's the code.

```
@login_manager.request_loader
def request_loader(req):
    email = req.form.get('email')
    if email not in users:
        return

    user = User()
    user.id = email

    # DO NOT ever store passwords in plaintext and always compare password
    # hashes using constant-time comparison!
    user.is_authenticated = req.form['pw'] == users[email]['pw']

    return user
```

Comment: `req.form` is a dictionary. `get` returns `None` if key not found, whereas the `[]` access throws `KeyError`

Comment: `request.args` are `GET` parameters, `request.form` are data submitted via `POST`  form

Comment: Thank you all for answers, I have understood the differences. Maybe the most helpful is the @Jean-FrançoisFabre answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper use-case get() is to return a default value when the key you are looking for doesn't exist in a dictionary.

For example, if you have a dictionary d such that :

```
d = {'foo': 'bar'}
```

Doing the following will return None:

```
d.get('baz', None)
```

While doing the following will throw an exception:

```
d['baz']
```